# Correct way to block a site if a cookie isn't present apache 2.4

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, session-cookies

I'm using apache 2.4.12 (Ubunutu 15.10) as an oauth2 proxy behind a node app. The app sends lots of unauthenticated requests before login b/c it doesn't know it's not authenticated (it doesn't know/care about the proxy) which creates lots of large cookies which can cause issues.

What I'd like to do is say if a particular cookie doesn't exist (mod_auth_openidc_session) -- which means it hasn't auth'd yet -- block all requests to my server. So far I have this but I'm not sure if this is correct (since the condition takes time to repro):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mod_auth_openidc_session
RewriteRule .*my.server.com.* [F]
```

Is this doing what I want?:

Block all requests to http(s)://my.server.com/ or http(s)://my.server.com/login etc unless the cookie mod_auth_openidc_session is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.server\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mod_auth_openidc_session
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/websocketpath            [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [F,L,NC]
```

So, this is what worked for me. Now all the unauth'd requests seem to get blocked that are creating lots of session states. I got the answer from a kind person at serverfault here:

[same question at serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/743056/correct-way-to-block-a-site-if-a-cookie-isnt-present-apache-2-4)